# Specify PHP ini file per vhost, with FastCGI/PHP-fpm configuration

Tags: php, apache

Okay, going slightly crazy trying to figure this out. (I have read hundreds of questions/answers, and google articles, but none have answered it)

I have just changed from using `mod_php` to using PHP through FastCGI and fpm, using the method described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal), purely because I was under the impression it was 'easy' to specify php.ini files for individual vhosts using this set-up.

What I'm pulling my hair out over, is how can I specify a custom PHP ini file each vhost uses?

Luckily, It's only on my test rig so far ... But I am hoping to do the same on my production server if I can ever figure this out

Comment: As far as my experience goes: you can define virtual host configurations per vhost (called `vhost.conf` on our server) although we have 1 php.ini for the whole server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought I may as-well post the whole process I took to configure fpm with pools, as @ChristianM mentioned, because I've not yet found a full explanation on how to do it.

The first part of this is mostly a copy of an AskUbuntu post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal/527227#comment905702_527227

The last part is how to configure pools, and get the vhost to use the relevent pool settings

Here it goes:

Install the apache mpm worker (Explanation of prefork/wroker and event at http://www.vps.net/blog/2013/04/08/apache-mpms-prefork-worker-and-event/):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
```

Install fastcgi and php5-fpm:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php5-fpm
```

Now enable mods you need, and disable those you don't:

```
sudo a2dismod php5 mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod actions fastcgi alias mpm_worker
```

Create the php5.fcgi file and give the webserver permission to use it.

```
sudo touch /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/lib/cgi-bin
```

Create a global config for php5-fpm

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/php5-fpm.conf
```

paste in the following (we'll use a socket instead of IP address)

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c> 
  AddHandler php5.fcgi .php 
  Action php5.fcgi /php5.fcgi 
  Alias /php5.fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi 
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600 
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory> 
</IfModule>
```

Note: Ensure all configs follow the same new 'Require all granted'/'Require all denied' syntax ... Otherwise you'll feel the pain after restarting ...

Enable the php5-fpm conf

```
sudo a2enconf php5-fpm
```

Restart apache and fpm

```
sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

This setup essentially creates a global fastcgi configuration for php, which uses the file /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini file.

If you have multiple vhosts, that are going to need different php configurations, continue with the example below

First, within the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d dir, you will find the default www.conf file. Copy this, naming it something relevent:

```
sudo cp /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/domain2.conf
```

Edit this file, changing the pool name:

```
[...]

[domain2]

[...]
```

And change name of the listen socket to something relevent:

```
[...]

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-domain2.sock

[...]
```

Then copy the /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi file, again naming it something relevent:

```
cp /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-domain2.fcgi
```

Now you're ready to add the mod_fastcgi module to the domain2 vhost. It's almost the same as the one described above, but notice the changes for 'Alias','FastCgiServer' and '-socket'

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain2.com

   [...]

   <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
     AddHandler php5.fcgi .php
     Action php5.fcgi /php5.fcgi
     Alias /php5.fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-domain2.fcgi
     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-domain2.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm-domain2.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  [...]

</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache and fpm

```
sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Now to test changes.

In your new /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/domain2.conf file, add a php value change (I've chosen the session.name value):

```
[...]

php_admin_value[session.name] = 'DOMAIN2'

[...]
```

Now test the configuration before restarting fpm:

```
sudo php5-fpm -t
```

It will tell you if the configuration fails, but more importantly will tell you if your configuration is fine. Then you can go ahead and restart fpm:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

And finally, if you want to be super sure the php value has been set, create info.php within your site, and just add:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set a php.ini file per vhost. What you can do is configure different php-fpm pools and give each a set of php configuration values that set/override something from the (shared) default config. See [fpm configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) on how to do that.

[Example config with different pools](https://github.com/perusio/php-fpm-example-config#features)

Comment: This seems to be the actual answer. No you can't. You can work around it by putting them in the fpm settings like the accepted answer describes, but you cannot specify a php.ini at all.

Comment: You can, but only if you set up a complete second php service with its own config files/paths specified.